# When low on food, should I sell beef to buy other cheaper foods?

Tags: banished

My village has a lot of cattle and thus produces a lot of beef. Beef has a sell value of 3, and many (non-meat) foods have a value of 1.

Is it a good idea to trade `n` units of beef to get `3n` units of some other stuff ?

If the answer is that it's a good idea, then do more expensive foods have any advantages over cheaper ones ?

This is not something I would necessarily do normally, but right now a food crisis is looming and I though this might be a good way to buy myself some time as I still have thousands units of beef in stock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm confident that's a fair trade as not only are you increasing your overall food stores, you're also increasing variety which is good for overall health.

Citizens in Banished require a variety of different types of food in order to maintain high health, this includes meats, vegetables, and fruits. The more variety, the more healthy your population will stay.